# Bash Scripting: greping the parameter

Tags: bash

Here is my problem. I have script and I want to make sure that the parameter that is entered when the script is called matches a variable name inside the script.

For example:

./valid foo <- being the script call

```
#!/bin/bash

PARAM=$1
VAR=/foo/

if grep -c $PARAM == $VAR
then
echo yes
fi

echo no
```

I am having the worst time using grep, I'm not sure how to use it properly inside of a script and after scouring the internet I think I need some specific feedback on my problem.

Thanks,

EA

Comment: Are you sure you need grep? Why not do `if ["$PARAM" == "$VAR"]`

Comment: Eric, should this be an exact match or a regular expression match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not robust, but you can do:

```
if echo "$VAR" | grep -q "$PARAM"; then
```

It is probably better to simply do:

```
if test "$VAR" = "$PARAM"; then
```

If you are trying to match a regex, bash allows:

```
if [[ "$VAR" =~ "$PARAM" ]]; then
```

to match the fixed string `$VAR` against the regex `$PARAM`.  If `$VAR` is the regex, you should reverse the order of the arguments.  (That is, `[[ "$PARAM" =~ "$VAR ]]`.)

Comment: Probably want `[[ $PARAM =~ $VAR ]]` -- looks like $VAR is the pattern.

Comment: @EricAnderson, note here that `$VAR` should be `"foo"` (without the slashes)

Comment: Maybe `[[ "$PARAM" =~ $VAR ]]` - PARAM might need quoting, VAR can't be quoted if it is supposed to be a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could search inside your script, since the declaration is the name followed by an equal sign:

```
if egrep "^\s*$PARAM=" $0
then 
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

to list variables use

```
set -o posix ; set
```

the posix thingie prevents listing of functions.

In order to isolate parameters local to script, run it from the shell and store the result,
then run it from your script and compare output

```
(set -o posix ; set) >/tmp/variables.before
(set -o posix ; set) >/tmp/variables.after
```